# iOS table view only loads data on device rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view and a custom cell that are loaded and set up but the problem is that the data isn't loaded unless I rotate the device. In portrait mode when I first run it there is nothing there, once I rotate the device either way all the data loads and works perfectly. Any suggestions?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    } 
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello"; return cell; 
}
```

Data loading -

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
    if (!error) { 
       NSLog(@"%@", objects);
       _postsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects]; 
    } else {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error loading the posts. Please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; 
       [alert show]; 
    } 
 }];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are loading your data asynchronously and not calling `reloadData` once the loading has completed.  You do call this method, but outside of the block so it will be executed immediately, before the load is completed.

Your data loading method should be -

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) { 
    if (!error) { 
       NSLog(@"%@", objects);
       _postsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects]; 
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{ 
           [self.tableView reloadData];
       });
    } else {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error loading the posts. Please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]; 
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
           [alert show]; 
       });
    } 
 }];
```

Note that operations that affect the UI need to be performed on the main queue.